# thymeleaf email template background-image not showing up

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have this thymeleaf based email template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title th:text="#{email.reset.title}">reset title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body th:style="'background: url(' + |cid:background| + ') no-repeat'">
    <div style="margin:110px 0 0 50px;">
        <div style="min-width:10px;min-height:300px"></div>
        <img style="display:block;margin-top:110px" th:src="|cid:logo|" />
        <img style="display:block;margin-top:110px" th:src="|cid:background|" />
    </div>
</body>
```

and I've defined two variable like this:

```
message.addInline( "logo", new ClassPathResource( "mails/images/logo.png" ), "image/png" );
message.addInline( "background", new ClassPathResource( "mails/images/background.png" ), "image/png" );
```

The two images from the `img` tag appear correctly in the email sent out, but the same image put as background for `body` is not showing up. Don't know why.

Using thymeleaf with java spring.

Comment: Did you get any solution ? Unfortunately I am running into same issue now.

Comment: @Krish couldn't find anything simple, so I renounced it

Comment: its not working in my case only when I logged into multiple google accounts in browser. its working fine with one google account. so I think its not our mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar a few months ago and I used the < body > like that:

```
<body th:style="'background: url(' + |cid:${background}| + ') no-repeat;'">
```

I wasn't able to use the variable correctly without the dollar sign $ and the curly brackets.

I hope this helps.

Comment: returns cid:null unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, am using like

```html
<body th style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-image: url(images/background.png)"
      data-th-style="|background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-color: #ccc; background-image: url(cid:background)|"
>
```

Its working for mobile phone but not in desktop. I am not sure whether its because of quality.
Still working on it.
Try this if its work.

Comment: Same issue for me, the logo shows up on mobile but not on Desktop :(